# Каким аналогом ctrl + w вы пользуетесь в Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rider

Долгое время я работал на IDE от JetBrains. Это были PhpStorm, Rider и т. д. У всех у них есть просто убойная фича: ctrl + w. Например, есть такой код:

```
var foo = new {
    Lol = 123,    
    Kek = "kek",
    KakDela = 22222
}
```

я ставлю курсор, например на `kek`, жму ctrl + w несколько раз и у меня полностью выделяется тело этого анонимного объекта. При первом нажатии выделится та конструкция, где установлен курсор. Если курсор будет в центре "kek", то будет выделено содержимое строкового литерала. Нажимая Ctrl + w мы увеличиваем поле выделения, захватывая новые и новые конструкции. Особенно это удобно во время отладки. Выделил таким образом нужную часть, вставил в immediate terminal и смотришь, что оно там возвращает.

Теперь я работаю в Visual Studio по ряду причин. Расскажите, кто читает, если сталкивались с переходами между этими IDE, как вы для себя заменили ctrl + w. Можно конечно Shift + стрелка влево/вправо, но это и близко не так удобно. Мышкой выделять - даже не рассматриваю, как альтернативу.

Comment: Да, кстати, решарпер тоже нельзя. Таковы правила. Голая студия. Только тру решения от майкросовта!

Comment: Ну вот плагин есть под VS [тут](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region) но он может только для php,html и js вроде. Но судя по всему вам это и нужно ?

Comment: Это для vs code мне просто под студию, но да, это оно. ctrl + w работает так же.

Comment: а, да точно) , ну может под студию какой то подобный плагин есть

Comment: Многое из райдера в студию переносит решарпер, но я не могу его использовать. Только то что дают майки из коробки или какие-то бесплатные решения. Кстати, особенно ctrl + w хорош с мультикурсором. Очень ускоряет работу.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Shift + Alt + =` - Edit.ExpandSelection

`Shift + Alt + ]` - Edit.ExpandSelectiontoContainingBlock

Первая комбинация увеличивает выделение по чуть-чуть, вторая выделяет сразу весь блок.

Если эти шорткаты кажутся неудобными, можно переназначить их в настройках Студии. Названия настроек я указал.

Comment: Да!! Спасибо, добрый человек, вот как оно тут называется!

Answer (score 0):

У меня работает Shift + Alt + right для последовательного расширения зоны выделения.  Если надо сократить зону выделения, то вместо right использовать left.
Норм, хотя ctrl + w в WebStorm удобнее..

Comment: Вероятно, у вас какое-то дополнение к Студии стоит.